# dma_alloc_coherent() returns NULL pointer

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, dma

I'm writing a driver for PCI device for Linux 3.13.3. I am trying to use DMA, but `dma_alloc_coherent()` always returns `NULL`. I'm trying to allocate 17 kB of memory (I tried power of two), but it always fails, returning `NULL` pointer.

```c
context->dma_addr = dma_alloc_coherent(context->adev->device, 
        AESDEV_DMA_SIZE, &context->dma_handle, GFP_KERNEL);
```

And that's how I set up the DMA, everything succeeds there:

```c
pci_set_master(pdev);

ret = pci_set_dma_mask(pdev, DMA_BIT_MASK(32));
if (ret) {
    dev_err(&pdev->dev, "set_dma_mask failed\n");
    goto setup_dma_failed;
}

ret = pci_set_consistent_dma_mask(pdev, DMA_BIT_MASK(32));
if (ret) {
    dev_err(&pdev->dev, "set_consistent_dma_mask failed\n");
    goto setup_dma_failed;
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `AESDEV_DMA_SIZE`?

Comment: this document: <https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/DMA-API-HOWTO.txt> discusses all the details of using DMA, including a statement to use the DMA API, not the PCI API.